# how to fade in and out background music when speech play and fade out audio at the end and mix them together using ffmpeg

Tags: php, audio, ffmpeg, yii2, command

I am using below command in my project to mix background music with my speech audio and background music slow down volume level when speech play:

```
ffmpeg -y -i speech.mp3 -stream_loop -1 -i music.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]asplit=2[sc][mix];[1:a][sc]sidechaincompress=threshold=0.01:ratio=5[bg];[mix][bg]amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=0[final]" -map [final] finalAudio.mp3
```

i want to add this two filter to audio:

1) Fade-in effect to background music for 1.5 sec when speech arrive and fade-out effect when speech is finish for 1.5 sec. speech.mp3 has more than one speech and silence in between speech.

2) Fade out effect at the end of audio for 1.5 sec.

can anyone help me to achieve both of above filter using ffmpeg with my above command?

Comment: Use the dynamic audio normalizer filter.

Comment: @szatmary can you post an example to use dynamic audio normalizer filter as of my question

Comment: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#dynaudnorm